# OnTriggerEnter works in Unity Editor, but does not detect any collision on Android or iOS

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I am facing a wearied issue. I have a few `TriggerCollider` in my game used to invoke different functions.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "StartPoint")
    {
        stones.SetActive(true);
        slidingCamera.SetActive(true);
        StartCoroutine("camerashake");
        StartCoroutine("najam1");
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
        controls.SetActive(false);
        col.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        hudScript.playParkingSound();
    }

    if(col.gameObject.tag == "EndPoint")
    {
        endParkingCamera.SetActive(true);
        col.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        controls.SetActive(false);
        arrow.SetActive(false);
        GameObject.Find("back1").transform.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("c");
        GameObject.Find("back2").transform.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("b");
        loaderVehicle.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
        StartCoroutine("WaitYar");
    }
}

IEnumerator WaitYar()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(4.0f);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Earning", hudScript.earning);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Time", (int) hudScript.mytime);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("GameOver", "LevelComplete");
    Application.LoadLevel("Game Over");
    StopCoroutine("WaitYar");
}

IEnumerator najam1()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(11.0f);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("VehicleSwitch", 2);
    hudScript.VehicleSwitch();
    controls.SetActive(true);
    StopCoroutine("najam1");
}
```

Every thing works on Unity Editor, but when I deploy it on Android or ios it doesn't detect any thing.

[Collision is being detected on Unity Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74Zyn.png)

Comment: Use a simple `Debug.Log` in the `OnTriggerEnter` function to see if your statement is true. If it works, put it in the `if` statement in that `OnTriggerEnter` function and see the outcome too

Comment: Bro it works fine on PC. i am facing this issue on Android and IOS devices

Comment: I know. You have already said that in the question. You have to do what I said in the first comment. You may want to comment the code in that function first.

Comment: @Programmer thanks for reply but i already have tried it and many of other things used `OnCollisionEnter` instead of  `OnTriggerEnter `, create new scripts, change vehicles, but unable to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is it related to a pluggin bug?

The exact same problem seems to be occurring here:

https://forum.unity.com/threads/collision-is-not-detected-on-device-wtf.322912/